# any non-negative function defined on a countable set can be considered as a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I was reading a theorem (Theorem 5.2.1 in here http://www.stat.colostate.edu/~estep/assets/chapter5.pdf ) and it seems to say any non-negative function defined on a countable set is actually a measure if defined this way:

Let $X$ be countable, and denoted $M$ as the power set of X, and $f:X $$\longrightarrow [0,\infty]$  be ANY function. Define $\mu(A) = \sum_{x\in A} f(x)$ where $A \in M$. Then $\mu$ is a measure on $M$.

My question is how to show it is a measure when defined that way.

I tried to show that countable additivity  and also $\mu(\emptyset)=0$ hold but not sure if it is correct.

For countable additivity, I assumed $A_i$ are disjoint, then I proceeded as this :

$\mu( \cup A_i) = \sum_{x \in \bigcup A_i} f(x) = \sum_{i}\sum_{x \in A_i} f(x) = \sum_{i} \mu(A_i)$

the first equality is by definition, the second equality is the one I am not sure of.

My question is, is this a correct proof of showing countable additivity holds?

Could someone comment on whether my procedure of proof is correct?
thank you

Also is there a specific name for such a theorem? because the author seems to be saying it is something important that can be regarded as a theorem on its own.

Comment: The proof is fine. For the second equality, you can use that the order of summation doesn't matter when the sum is absolutely summable.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your comment on the proof of the Countable-additivity part. But for the other part i.e. $\mu( \emptyset) = 0$, could you give some hint as to how to show that? because it seems the author says the "non-negativity" of the function f, and countability of $X$ are keys. But I am not sure how to use those two properties to show that the measure of empty set is zero yet. Could you give some hint or comments.

Comment: That is basically a convention- how do you treat a sum with zero summands. It is a reasonable convention, because it guarantees that $\sum_{x\in A\cup B}f(x)=\sum_{x\in A}f(x)+\sum_{x\in B}f(x)$.